# Linux / Ruby / mpv script => Android /?

Tags: music, mp3

I am on Fedora Linux for years I have had a Ruby script which creates a list of MP3s from a directory, randomises the order of the list and then plays the list using mpv.  I have mpv for Android.

What would be the simplest way to reproduce the Ruby script for Android? - I have played around with rooting my phones in the past but I would prefer not to have to do that this time . .

Comment: You may be able to execute your script in [Termux](https://termux.dev/en/) app after executing `termux-setup-storage` to get access to your media files.

Comment: If you are using a specific MPV player app on Android, you should edit your post to link to it, and mention which version you are running. Note that the creator of the MPV app may have additional features for play order/sorting which might be able to cover your needs.